# Grepping only certain lines of files

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a collection of files in a directory which I would like to search for a particular regular expression (`=([14-9]|[23][0-9])`, as it happens). But I only care when this pattern falls on the second, sixth, tenth, ..., 4n+2-th line.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass it through `awk` first to get rid of the unwanted lines (and optionally put on line numbers so that you can still tell what the real lines are):

```
pax> echo 'L1
...> L2
...> L3
...> L4
...> L5
...> L6
...> L7
...> L8
...> L9
...> L10
...> L11
...> L12' | awk '{if ((FNR % 4)==2) {print FNR":"$0}}'
2:L2
6:L6
10:L10
```

(just use `'{if ((FNR % 4)==2) {print}}'` if you don't care about the line numbers). So something like:

```
awk '{if ((FNR % 4)==2) {print FNR":"$0}}' inputFile | grep '(=([14-9]|[23][0-9])'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! A slight modification, awk '{if ((FNR % 4)==2) {print FNR":"$0}}' * | egrep '=([14-9]|[23][0-9])' worked great.

Answer (score 2):

modification to the answer without using extra grep,

```
awk '/(=([14-9]|[23][0-9])/ && FNR % 4==2{print FNR":"$0}}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do this with awk. Someting like

```
BEGIN     {i=0; n=0; }

/yourregegex/  {
               if(i==n) { print $0; n= 4*i+2;}
               }

               {
               i++;
               }
```